# How to specify 99th percentile for a Datadog widget with distribution_definition via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, datadog

For example, a widget is created via:

```
widget {
    distribution_definition {
       request {
           q = "some-query"
       }
       title = "some-title"
    }
}
```

Looking at the [API document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard), it looks like there is no `percentile` aggregator support for `distribution_definition`. How should we specify 99th percentile (p99) for the widget?

Comment: If the API endpoint supports the parameter, then you may want to go file a feature request with the provider.

Comment: What do you mean by specify the percentile? The percentiles are a statistical subset of the result set, so I believe they are calculated rather than specified.